# Insert into String and preserve original variable state

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm renaming files based on a text file of names produced from a database dump. I'm doing a directory listing and checking each if it contains an "_P2.PSD". If the file contains that sub-string I loop through 3 different places where an underscore could be and see if that string exists in a file. If I find a match based off of the contents of the file, I will rename the image with that format.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
Dir.glob("#{directory}").each do |file|
  if "#{file.include? ("_P2")}" == "true"
    if File.readlines("#{db_Dump}").grep(/#{file.insert(-11, '_')}/).size > 0
      logger.info{"#{file}"}
      #mod_file =   file.insert(-11, '_')
      #logger.info{"#{file} -> #{mod_file}"}
    elsif File.readlines("#{db_Dump}").grep(/#{file.insert(-10, '_')}/).size > 0
      logger.info{"#{file}"}
      #mod_file =   file.insert(-10, '_')
      #logger.info{"#{file} -> #{mod_file}"}
    elsif File.readlines("#{db_Dump}").grep(/#{file.insert(-9, '_')}/).size > 0
      logger.info{"#{file}"}
      #mod_file =   file.insert(-9, '_')
      #logger.info{"#{file} -> #{mod_file}"}
    else
      logger.info{"NO_UNDERSCORE_PLACEMENT_FOUND -> #{file}"}
    end
  end
end
```

The real issue:

```
irb(main):001:0> bob="ThisIsDefaultText"
=> "ThisIsDefaultText"
irb(main):002:0> puts bob.insert(-5,'_')
ThisIsDefault_Text
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts bob
ThisIsDefault_Text
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: What's with `"#{file.include? ("_P2")}" == "true"`? This isn't bash. Just do `file.include?("_P2")`. Likewise, all instances of `"#{x}"` can be replaced with `x`, there's no need for stringifying a string.

Comment: It's called String Interpolation. It's more of less of a habit at this point. It isn't needed for that instance no, but if I were wanting to add to this string I *WOULD* need to do that or concatenate. I do not like doing 

`var1 = bob
puts var1 + ' is an engineer'
`. 

That looks quite dirty to me when I can just use 

`var1 = bob
"#{var1} is an engineer"
`

So by doing that often, I **usually** wrap my variables in that by habit and my readability.

Comment: I do understand however there is some additional overhead and if the script is going to need to scale I would need to remove the additional and unnecessary processing of casting a string to a string. Thanks for keeping me straight ;)

Comment: Yes, that is one form of string interpolation, but it's pointless when you're not adding anything to the string. It's even borderline ridiculous when you're casting the results of a function call to a string and comparing that to a string when the return value is a boolean. If you're looking for readability, use the *minimal* representation. `x = y` is better than `x = "#{y}"` every time. Don't forget `"%s is an engineer" % var1` is also an option.

Answer (score 3):

```
bob = "ThisIsDefaultText"
puts bob.dup.insert(-5, '_')
#=> ThisIsDefault_Text
puts bob
#=> ThisIsDefaultText
```

The the String parent Object has a duplicate method .dup that will "produce a shallow copy".

Comment: This could work too  "#{bob[0..-5]}_#{bob[-4..-1]}" but it's dirty, wurde answer is the correct one.